# Bind datatable to Checkbox list with horizontal repeat?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

This is for a `Windows Form`.

We have a `DataTable` that looks like the following:

```
EmplId

A101
A102
A103
A104
A105
B101
B102
B103
B104
```

Is it possible to bind a set of comboboxes to this DataTable so it looks something like this?

[image]

If that's not possible, what other suggestions do you have where I can display this `DataTable` into a set of controls that I can then select?

I know I can use a `CheckedListBox`, but I want repeat direction to be horizontal. And it seems that `CheckedListBox` doesn't have a `RepeatDirection` property.
Thanks.

Comment: Loop through it, create your checkbox controls and attach them to your form or parent control.

Comment: Do you mean by using a `CheckedListBox`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can improve it as you like :

```
            int x = 4;
            int y = 4;
            foreach (DataRow dt in YourDataTable.Rows)
            {
                x = 4;
                y = panel1 .Controls.Count * 20;
              CheckBox ck=new CheckBox() ;
                ck.Text =dt[2].ToString ();

                 ck.Width = 450;  //  determine the width to fit 3 columns
                ck.Location = new Point(x, y);
                ck.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(MyEven);   
                Form1.Controls .Add (ck);

            }
```

Add this method for handel the CheckedChanged :

```
public void MyEven(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chek = (CheckBox)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("Check is pressed " + chek.Text);

        }
```

//read all the checked checkboxes

```
 foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                if (c is CheckBox)
                {
                    CheckBox ck = (c as CheckBox);
                    if (ck.Checked)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Check " + ck.Text + " is chcked");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. So I added a `Panel` to my `Form`, and included your code, but I'm receiving a compiler error in line `Form1.Controls .Add (ck);`. Instead of using _Form1_ I used the name of my Form.

Comment: I you have a panel ("Panel1") in you form you can use :Panel1.Controls .Add (ck);

Comment: It works similar to the `CheckedListBox`. Can this be done horizontally? And how do I read the values of the checked controld?

Comment: I have Edit my answer for show you how  read the values of the checked controld .If my answer was helpful for you please mark it . Thanks

Comment: If I change the 20 to another anumber, I notice a difference in vertical spacing between the checkboxes. But it's only shown in one column.

Comment: Ok just change Panel with flowLayoutPanel , it's work perfectly with multiColumns

Comment: It works somewhat; how can I determine the width of the checkbox so that I can fit 3 columns instead of 2? The width of my `flowLayoutPanel` is 300.

Comment: I can read the checkboxes selected. I only need to fit more than two columns into the `flowLayoutPanel`

Comment: Have a look at my answer i have edit it for changing with and read all the checked checkboxes ,

Comment: Ok i find it , use tableLayoutPanel  and add a column as 3 colums or a number as you like ,and enjoy

Comment: Your answer is not working and you didn't test it. I cannot mark it as answer.

Comment: i test it it 's work fine are you using  tableLayoutPanel  ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the `TableLayoutPanel` onto the form. Set `ColumnCount` property to 3.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    var checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.Text = row["EmpId"].ToString();
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(checkBox);
}
```